# how to convert xml attributes to table columns using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xml like this:

`<root>
  <row col1="value1" col2="value2" ...... coln="valuen"/>
  <row col1="value1" col2="value2" ...... coln="valuen"/>
  .
  .
  .
<row col1="value1" col2="value2" ...... coln="valuen"/>
</root>`

How do I convert this into a table attribute names as column names and attribute values as column values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work, assuming that each row has the same number of attributes:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:output method="html" />

    <xsl:template match="/root">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="row[1]" mode="header"/>
                </tr>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="row" mode="rows"/>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row" mode="header">
        <xsl:for-each select="attribute::*">
            <th><xsl:value-of select="local-name(.)" /></th>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="row" mode="rows">
        <tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="attribute::*">
                <td><xsl:value-of select="." /></td>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If there might be additional attributes that don't represent column values, you'd need to filter out those by checking the name or something.